# Splitting an array/list into pairs and then perform aggregation

Tags: c#, python, linq, split, aggregate

Consider I've an array of integers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} and I want to pair them up as {{1,2},{3,4} and so on} and perform subtraction on the pair and finally sum the results.

Following is the code I've now and for better understanding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] ints = { 4, 8, 8, 3, 9, 0, 7, 8, 2, 2 };

    ints = ints.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x=>x).ToArray();

    List<int> lints = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < ints.Length; i = i + 2, j = j + 2)
    {
        lints.Add(ints.ElementAtOrDefault(j) - ints.ElementAtOrDefault(i));
    }

    int lintsum = lints.Sum();

    Console.WriteLine(lintsum);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in linq in C#? And how can I do the same in python?

Comment: & where is your Python code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) which has a `Pairwise` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` which does exactly what you want, it invokes a delegate on an element and its predecessor:

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = ints.Pairwise((first, second) => second - first);
Console.WriteLine(result.Sum());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the result using Python in the following way:

```
In [25]: start = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [26]: tuples = [item for item in zip(start[::2], start[1::2])]

In [27]: tuples
Out[27]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]

In [28]: answer = sum(rhs-lhs for (lhs, rhs) in tuples)

In [29]: answer
Out[29]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using Python is:

```
ints = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print sum(y - x for x, y in zip(*([iter(ints)] * 2)))

ints = [4, 8, 8, 3, 9, 0, 7, 8, 2, 2]
print sum(y - x for x, y in zip(*([iter(ints)] * 2)))
```

Giving:

```
4
-9
```

Answer (score 1):

When using large arrays of number, it might be preferable to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
ints = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
tuples = ints.reshape(-1,2))
```

Then take the difference and sum

```
(tuples[:,1]-tuples[:,0]).sum()
```

Or alternatively

```
np.diff(tuples).sum()
```